# What is the solution for printing plastic ID cards from a PHP/MySQL Application?

Tags: printing, php, id

I have a student management system written in PHP with a MySQL backend and I need to implement a solution to print the student's College ID to a plastic ID Card Printer.

The possible solutions i can see are:

1) My PHP application generates a 85.60 × 53.98 PDF which is then printed using printer drivers supplied by the ID-card Printer manufacturer. This would be the simplest, but as yet I have been unable to confirm any printer that will correctly (with scale, centering) print from a PDF. They all seem to have their own custom design software.

2) I use some ID-Card software that can read the student's information either directly from MySQL, or via ODBC, and that can also generate a barcode and read an image file from a path retrieved from the database.

I want to be careful not to ask for a specific shopping recomendation here, but I would appreciate hints towards which ID card manufacturers to approach as searching the web has not turned up any concrete, positive results for a suitable printer/software solution.